# WPF adjust font size to window ratio

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a good wait to adjust font size according to window size?
I have a loading image that resizes / stretches to the window size.
In the center of it is a label with the status of the current process.

What would be the best way to increase or decrease the font size according to the window size to make sure the label content never overlaps the image?

Comment: can you describe in more details why there is a need to enlarge the image and label?

Comment: Couldn't you handle the SizeChanged event of the Window and have a global FontSize that is changed to discrete sizes whenever you window reaches a certain size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [ViewBox](http://wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html) that can be applied to the hole window.

Comment: A ViewBox would scale the font in all directions, and it could look horrible if the ratio is funny.

Comment: may be this is what Tsukasa looking for

Comment: Viewbox would work perfectly here, to stop it skewing the text you should set the "Stretch" property to "Uniform" this will ensure the text maintains its   aspect ratio